# How do you check if a terminal is compatible with a connector?

Tags: connector, terminal, wire-terminals

In example, if I was looking for a terminal for [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/282087-1/1860707?utm_adgroup=Rectangular%20Connectors%20-%20Housings&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_Product_Connectors%2C%20Interconnects&utm_term=&utm_content=Rectangular%20Connectors%20-%20Housings&gclid=Cj0KCQiAr5iQBhCsARIsAPcwROM28ak59Em_tBc3lzqtrcBkfc7VI5QaqkAQOOA4g-gZgdcm9m_kTvMaAr8hEALw_wcB) type of connector. I'm looking through terminals but I don't really know how to make sure they'll be a fit for each other. In a general way, how do you check for compatibility between any connector and any terminal?

Comment: I'd contact DigiKey directly.  I am sure they have someone who works with these AMP connectors regularly and they can advise you on the correct pins for your application.  My guess is that there are many choices.

Comment: You can also look at the manufacturer's data sheet for the series.  Here:  https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Catalog+Section%7F1654292_AMP_SUPERSEAL_1_5_SERIES%7F0616%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_CS_1654292_AMP_SUPERSEAL_1_5_SERIES_0616.pdf%7F282087-1

Comment: @jwh20 Thanks! That document helps out a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I'm trying to choose a terminal for this type of connector. I'm
> looking through terminals but I don't really know how to make sure
> they'll be a fit for each other. How do you check this?*

Just scroll down the linked page to find this: -

[image]

Comment: What if the website did not have those listed? This website does a good job of telling you, but not all are that good at telling you this.

Comment: @eWizard search for a certain product family on the manufacturer's website.

Comment: @eWizard then I'd find the part listed on the manufacturer's website and see what it tells you. If it didn't tell you what it mated with or what the associated products were then I'd consider not using the part else, I'd email the manufacturer. `but not all are that good at telling you this.` - all the proper supply chain distributors actually are. If you decide to use Shamazon or pee-bay or mali-baba or bung-bad then that's a different problem entirely.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks, this was the answer I was looking at. I keep looking at the datasheets and I just wasn't able to tell with just the datasheet of one connector and was trying to figure it out with just that.